# Anonymous users modifying realtime documents

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to let anonymous (not signed in users) be able to modify a realtime document. It appears that [as of a year ago this wasn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642598/how-to-let-anonymous-users-edit-a-google-drive-realtime-document). I'm hoping that there has been some progress since then.

I have created a real-time document using my app and have set the sharing settings so that anyone with the link can edit the file.

When I try to load the document, it tries to make a request to:

GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/gs?access_token=null&id=FILEID 401 (Unauthorized) api:160
Drive Realtime API Error: token_refresh_required: The OAuth token must be refreshed.

Obviously with a null access token and not having a way to specify a browser key this won't work. Is there a way to make this happen?

I'm hoping that in the last year there has been some new status on this that I couldn't find in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access realtime documents anonymously.  All users must be signed in to a Google account.

Comment: Not sure if possible but, what if he has a server that has a saved refresh token from a fixed google account and the server can return access tokens from it? From the js side get an access token from that server. This means more than one user will use the same access token. Might not work and/or be against google's t.o.s.

Comment: That sounds like a horrible idea, and shouldn't be possible.  You are going to give random user access to someone else's drive?

Comment: Thanks Cheryl for the response. Can you give any information as to whether there is any planned support for this down the line? Is it on the roadmap?

Comment: No, not to the whole drive. The server would configure the scopes so it only gives a token for that single realtime doc. I know its a bad idea but why wouldnt it work?