# Is it necessary to verify my app in order to write data to google sheet?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I have already used google sheets API before, but it seems now they have new policy, so I can't add the required scope that allows you to write data (in my case - metadata) to a spreadsheet (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets) without verification. (I get 403: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.")
Is there any way to write data to a spreadsheet, even just for developing (maybe write only to a sheet that I have created as the owner of the project) without verification, or maybe I'm doing something wrong? 
[image: In short: this is my problem]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to let anonymous users edit a Google Drive Realtime document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642598/how-to-let-anonymous-users-edit-a-google-drive-realtime-document)

Comment: @Kredns No. It's not about anonymous user, it's about a logged-in user that has an access token, but cannot write the document because the app is not verified (and thus cannot get the required scope)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google Sheets API documentation:

> When your application requests private data, **the request must be authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data**.
>
> Every request your application sends to the Google Sheets API needs to identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify your application: using an OAuth 2.0 token (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the application's API key.

Therefore, the scope you are using, the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` is the one which allows reading and/or writing acces to the user's sheets and their properties and it **requires** authorization.

So what you can do to solve your issue, is to use a **service account**.

You should [create](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) one for your project in the API console and then your application will make authorized requests by using the account's credentials to request the access token from the OAuth 2.0 server. Hence, the authentication procedure won't be necessary every time since the application will be calling the API on behalf of the service account.

Furthermore, I suggest you take a look at these links, since they might be of help:

1. [Authorize Request with Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing);
2. [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount);
3. [Using OAuth 2.0 to Acces Google's APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: I send the request both with the app API key and the OAuth access token, but I cannot use this scope because it's a sensitive scope the app is not verified.

Comment: Hello @Moshe! The warning message is about the **Sensitive scope verification** and it's needed to ensure that your app's usage of these scopes are not deceptive and to protect user data. Have you tried marking the app as being internal-only in the OAuth consent screen? Try [this link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en) and follow the steps from the **How can I mark my app as internal-only so it doesn't require verification?**. What results are you getting? Cheers!